# Xcode 7 issue when archive a project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an Xcode project that runs perfect on all devices (on iOS 8.0+).

But, When I Try to Archive the project for a Build Xcode tells me the following error:

```
Libtool /Users/Matteo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nanopress-figspgsknggpljajziptkxtunnnw/ArchiveIntermediates/NanoPress/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DTFoundation.build/Release-iphoneos/DTHTMLParser\ (iOS).build/Objects-normal/armv7/libDTHTMLParser_iOS.a normal armv7
    cd /Users/Matteo/Downloads/nanopress_updated-3/External/DTCoreText/Core/Externals/DTFoundation
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only armv7 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/Matteo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nanopress-figspgsknggpljajziptkxtunnnw/ArchiveIntermediates/NanoPress/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/Matteo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nanopress-figspgsknggpljajziptkxtunnnw/ArchiveIntermediates/NanoPress/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DTFoundation.build/Release-iphoneos/DTHTMLParser\ (iOS).build/Objects-normal/armv7/DTHTMLParser_iOS.LinkFileList /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib -framework Foundation -o /Users/Matteo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nanopress-figspgsknggpljajziptkxtunnnw/ArchiveIntermediates/NanoPress/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DTFoundation.build/Release-iphoneos/DTHTMLParser\ (iOS).build/Objects-normal/armv7/libDTHTMLParser_iOS.a

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib (No such file or directory)
```

I Try to clean the Project and delete derived data but it doesn't work.

The main project includes a subproject: DTCoreText

Thank you

[image]

Comment: When it comes to DTCoreText i find the installation such a tremendous pain that you are better off using Cocoapods to install rather than by yourself

Comment: @MaTTP ...did you find any solution for it?

Comment: No sorry I don't find any solution. Only solution is build with Xcode 6.4